# Neos 2.0 Breadcrumb menu: How to skip first two levels?

Tags: neoscms

I need to display a breadcrumb menu where the first two levels are skipped.

Menus of type `Menu` have a property `entryLevel` to control where the menu starts, but it seems that is not the case for `Breadcrumb`. (At least it has no effect.)

Is there a way to accomplish this in Neos?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Breadcrumb is defined in `TYPO3.Neos/Resources/Private/TypoScript/Prototypes/Breadcrumb.ts2` and you can overwrite values from there in Root.ts2 in your site package. So you can change `templatePath` and handle it using iterator in `f:for` or even better just limit (slice) `items` you pass to template on TS2 level. Translating it to code, you have `Your.Site.Package/Resources/Private/TypoScript/Root.ts2` and there your page definition, just change Breadcrumb part:

```
page = Page {
    ...
    body {
        templatePath = 'resource://Your.Site.Package/Private/Templates/Page/Default.html'
        sectionName = 'body'
        parts {
            menu = Menu
            breadcrumb = Breadcrumb {
                # replace items with itemCollection if you're using BreadcrumbMenu (Neos 2+)
                items = ${q(node).add(q(node).parents('[instanceof TYPO3.Neos:Document]')).slice(0, -2).get()}
            }
        }
    ...
```

Comment: Thanks, this works – at least when changing `items` to `itemCollection`. (I forgot to mention that it’s Neos 2; maybe `items` would be correct in Neos 1.)